# What is the correct razor syntax for nested and mixed code blocks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have razor syntax that's nested and mixed in with html and javascript.

It runs fine except when I do a auto code format, the `}` keeps getting push out of place.

```
@section js{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            @if (ViewBag.Searched && ViewBag.Found)
            {
                @:$('#found').show(); $('#permit-info').show();

                @if (ViewBag.PendingRequest)
                {
                    @:$('#request-info').hide(); $('#report-info').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    @:$('#request-info').show(); $('#report-info').hide();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                @if (ViewBag.Searched)
                {
                    @:$('#not-found').show();
                            } // <----- PROBLEM. this } doesn't stay at the right place.
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `@` on this line:

```
@if (ViewBag.Searched)
```

and this line:

```
@if (ViewBag.PendingRequest)
```

Because you're already in razor code (governed by the parent `if`/`else` statements).

Actually, that still kills the format. **Although**, if you try using `<text>` tags instead of `@:` it works. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        @if (ViewBag.Searched && ViewBag.Found)
        {
            <text>$('#found').show(); $('#permit-info').show();</text>

            if (ViewBag.PendingRequest)
            {
                <text>$('#request-info').hide(); $('#report-info').show();</text>
            }
            else
            {
                <text>$('#request-info').show(); $('#report-info').hide();</text>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ViewBag.Searched)
            {
                <text>$('#not-found').show();</text>
            }
        }
    });
```

**Take note: Visual Studio always indents razor views poorly :)**

Comment: I removed it, but still having the same problem.

Comment: @RayCheng I've just edited, you actually have 2 lines with an extra `@`

Comment: @RayCheng It works for me with `<text>` tags. Check my new edit :)

Comment: That works but why? `<text>` is not a valid html tag but it's not a razor tag either.

Comment: @RayCheng `<text>` is part of Razor, it's an alternative to `@:` (more useful usually for multi-line statements) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I just found that article also.